# How do I figure out the errors that appear in the terminal when I install Node.js and npm?

Tags: nodejs, npm

I tried to install npm and Node.js to my computer today. The operating system in my computer is Ubuntu 20.04LTS. But when it was installing there were a whole bunch of errors in my terminal. It will really be appreciated if anyone can help me to figure it out.

These are the errors in my terminal when installing npm:

[image: errors in my terminal when installing npm]

These are the errors in my terminal when installing Node.js:

[image: errors in my terminal when installing nodejs]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use  code formatting instead: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code